# Twig render field with a string

Tags: templates, twig

I have a template like

```
{% for item in items %}
   <div class="active">{{ item.values.color }}</div>
   ...
{% endfor %}
```

then I have another block in which I use again `item.values.color` like:

```
{% for item in items %}
   <section class="random">{{ item.values.color }}</div>
   ...
{% endfor %}
```

Because I'm using several times `item.values.color` in different part of my template, I tried to set a variable

```
{% set color = item.values.color %}
```

and then tried to use it like this:

```
{{ color }}
```

in one of the template above, but it does not seem to work. Any thought?

Answer (score 0):

`{% set color = item.values.color %}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
{% set color %} {# set default color if required #}

{% for item in items %}
   {% set color = item.values.color %}
   <section class="random">{{ color }}</div>
   ...
{% endfor %}

{# use in other blocks #}
{{ color }}
```